# Python creating directory gives IO error

Tags: python

I extract the directory name from the path which is BounceOM, then i have a filename which is HelloWorld.
I want to create new folder 'HelloWorld' in the BounceOM directory. I use os.path.join

```
filename=os.path.basename(str(htmlfile)).replace('.mat',' ')
path=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(str(resultfile)))
newpath=os.path.join(path,filename)
```

my new path prints, C:\Users\rain1_000\Desktop\python\BounceOM\HelloWorld

Then I try to create the directory

```
if not os.path.exists(newpath): 
    os.makedirs(newpath)
```

I want to store some files in the new directory, but it gives me `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`: But when I look into the directory, Helloworld directory is created,

But when I append single quotes to the filename and create the directory then it does not gives me error and result files are written to the newly created directory

```
report1='\''+filename+'\''
newpath=os.path.join(path,report1)
```

my new path prints, C:\Users\rain1_000\Desktop\python\BounceOM\'HelloWorld' and there is no problem in creating and writing the result files.

I don't understand what is the real problem

Comment: you should be using `/` slashes or  raw string `r` in your paths, `\\` is an escape character in python

Comment: Could you post a full set of code that demonstrates the error? It seems likely that the error is caused by something you haven't shown us.

Comment: i used forward slashes also but still it is giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think single quotes should not be the problem. Can you try other folder name without single quotes and check

Comment: that was as typing mistake, but that was not the problem, but when i put the path is new program and try to create the directory it is creating and writing the files

Comment: but when i append single quotes to the filename and create new directory there is no problem like C:\Users\rain1_000\Desktop\python\BounceOM\'HelloWorld'

Comment: Do u know what is difference between appending a single quotes to the filename and without singlequotes